# Jekyll every 4th item in loop display differently

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, jekyll, liquid

I am using jekyll to populate my blog page with blog posts. I want there to be two posts for every `div` with the "row" class, but I also want every 4th item to be an ad (skip over the post and move to the next row but still include something else that's not a post).

So if there are 6 posts, the output should look like this

```
<div class="row"> <!-- 1st row -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 1st post, no skip -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 2nd post, no skip -->
</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- 2nd row -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 3rd post, no skip -->
  <div> THIS IS NOT A POST </div>  <!-- skip post 4, put something else -->
</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- 3rd row -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 4th post, because last item was skipped to display something else -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 5th post, no skip -->
</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- 4th row -->
  <div> {{ post.title }} </div>  <!-- 6th post, no  skip -->
</div>

<!-- and so on, so every 4th item is not a post, but the posts continue after the skipped post -->
```

I have the post loop part but I cant figure out how to add the SKIP

```
{% assign rows = site.posts.size | divided_by: 2.0 | ceil %}
{% for i in (1..rows) %}
  {% assign offset = forloop.index0 | times: 2 %}
  <div class="row blogitems">
    {% for post in site.posts limit:2 offset:offset %}
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just walk through your items while checking the [modulo](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/math-filters#modulo). Like this:

```
<div class="row blogitems">
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign mod3 = forloop.index | modulo: 3 %}
  <div class="col-md-6"><p>{{ post.title }}</p></div>
  {% if mod3 == 0 %}<div class="col-md-6"><p>THIS IS NOT A POST</p>{% endif %}
  {% if mod3 == 0 or mod3 == 2 %}</div><div class="row blogitems">{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the perfect and succint answer! Here's a live version of my blog if you want to check out how it looks :) https://somiibo.com/blog/

Comment: You are welcome. Nice blog. My only remark: something is wrong with the preloader. Site loads (I see the site), then the preloader shows, then the site shows again.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, it's helpful to know stuff like that! I'm not sure why that happens because the css for the preloader is fetched at the top of the page :/